# error while doing lseek on a timer fd

Tags: c, posix, flush

This post:

[Empty or "flush" a file descriptor without read()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924173/empty-or-flush-a-file-descriptor-without-read)

, says that it is possible to do a `lseek()` on a fd you don't want to read from, thereby avoiding unnecessary copying, but this does not apply to fds I create with `timerfd_create()`. Why is this so and does there exist a workaround (except to use `read()`, which works).

I try to do `lseek()` like this:

```
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
```

And `strerror()` returned `Illegal seek`. Again, `read(fd, buffer, 8)` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timer_fd`s are not seekable. Not every `fd` is. Use `read` to read the relevant bytes.

Note that contrary to the `POSIX` tag, these calls are Linux specific. From the man page:

```
CONFORMING TO
       These system calls are Linux-specific.
```

Comment: Well I know, but a timer fd is not a fifo, nor a pipe. Where do the posix specs say that I can't do `lseek` on a timer fd? Workaround?

Comment: They don't because `timer_fd` is Linux specific, and does not form part of the POSIX standard. The spec is thus the Linux kernel source.

Comment: Linux does not support seeking of `timer_fd`. I have told you the workaround, which is to use `read` to read the relevant bytes.

Comment: Yeah, but is this the only way? I don't want to lose even a nanosecond on a pointless ``read()`.

Comment: You could patch the kernel to make it seekable :-)