# how to get the minimum amount of bytes to read() from a file descriptor?

Tags: c, linux, timer, file-descriptor

**Edit**

My primary goal was to just flush a readable file descriptor after `select()` notified incoming data. This goal is achieved for me now by just providing `read()` with a big enough buffer as pointed out by Basile Starynkevitch. This is why I mark this answer accepted.

The question in the title is not answered yet though: how do I get the minimum number of bytes I can read from a file descriptor like this:

```
min_size = fd_get_chunksize(file_descriptor);
```

which might return 1, 4, 8 or something else.

**Original Question**

I have a couple of file descriptors created in different ways. E.g. with `timerfd_create()` and configured it to fire once a second.

When `select()` signals traffic on a certain FD I want to flush it. For the ones created with `timerfd_create()` I have to read *8* bytes minimum:

```
if(select(fd + 1, &l_fdsRd, NULL, NULL, &l_timeOut)) {
    unsigned long long data;
    int count;
    while((count = read (fd, &data, sizeof(data))) > 0) {
        printf("%d %ld\n", count, data);
    }
}
```

When `data` is declared as `char` and thus sizeof(data) is 1, `count` is always `0` and my file descriptor never gets flushed.

In case I have more than one file descriptor to flush (maybe created differently) I have to know the number of bytes for every file descriptor I have to read to flush it.

Is there a way to get this amount of bytes for an existing FD?

Is there another way to flush a file descriptor I've created with `timerfd_create()`? (I read [Empty or "flush" a file descriptor without read()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924173/empty-or-flush-a-file-descriptor-without-read) but this gave me no answer..)
Actually I don't want to read the content but just want to make it ready for `select()` again.

Comment: This would appear to be C++, not C...may apply to both languages, but please update your tags accordingly.

Comment: IMHO,  `timerfd_create` should have been mentioned in the title!

Comment: Maybe my post was misleading. FDs created with `timerfd_create` are just one sort of file descriptors I want to monitor. After `select()` returned on one of them I have to flush it. Since I want to do this generically I have to know *how* to flush them. E.g. I have to know how many bytes to read.

Comment: @tonysdg: It's a C question. I just forgot to remove the `std::cout`. But `timerfd_create`, `select()`, `read()` etc. are not C++

Comment: Did you consider the FIONBIO ioctl(2) ? I don't recommend it, but it probably is giving the number of readable bytes you are dreaming about. BTW, perhaps you just want non-blocking IO or async IO à la [aio_read(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/aio_read.3.html) ... you really should motivate your question (why do you need to flush input) and explain *why you are asking it* by editing it to improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read carefully [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html)

> Operating on a timer file descriptor
>
> ```
>   The file descriptor returned by timerfd_create() supports the
>    following operations:
>
>   read(2)
>           If the timer has already expired one or more times since its
>           settings were last modified using timerfd_settime(), or since
>           the last successful read(2), then the buffer given to read(2)
>           returns an unsigned 8-byte integer (uint64_t) containing the
>           number of expirations that have occurred.  (The returned value
>           is in host byte order—that is, the native byte order for
>           integers on the host machine.)
>
>          If no timer expirations have occurred at the time of the
>           read(2), then the call either blocks until the next timer
>           expiration, or fails with the error EAGAIN if the file
>           descriptor has been made nonblocking (via the use of the
>           fcntl(2) F_SETFL operation to set the O_NONBLOCK flag).
>
>          A read(2) will fail with the error EINVAL if the size of the
>           supplied buffer is less than 8 bytes.
>
>   poll(2), select(2) (and similar)
>           The file descriptor is readable (the select(2) readfds
>           argument; the poll(2) POLLIN flag) if one or more timer
>           expirations have occurred.
> ```

So **you** really **should read an unsigned 8 byte integer** when the file descriptor is readable. Notice that you cannot read only a single byte (`EINVAL` error mentioned)

Hence declare

```
uint64_t data;
```

For ordinary file descriptors, *you* know how many bytes should you read. Perhaps it is a pipe or a socket (or a mouse device) with *small* fixed length messages. But in general, you'll better **[read](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) a large enough buffer** (typically, ***several kilobytes***, up to a megabyte; perhaps 64Kbytes = 65536 bytes could be a not-too-bad tradeoff). Notice that [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)
 is returning on success a byte count so can be a partial read. If some bytes remain immediately readable, the next [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or the nearly obsolete `select`) will succeed immediately.

See also the paragraph about *Pipe Capacity* in [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)

You might also consider the old `FIONBIO` [ioctl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) but I don't recommend using it (it is not very portable, with a not very well defined semantics : it *might* give the number of *available* bytes to read). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1150635/841108).

Avoid [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)-ing very small buffers (of a few bytes). In particular, `read`-ing one byte at a time is always giving abyssal performance.

BTW, some hardware block devices may want to [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) in multiple of some block size, which generally fits in a few kilobytes (e.g. a page or two). YMMV.

Perhaps asynchronous IO (see [aio(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html)) might be useful.

Comment: This is right but not the answer to my question. I've updated the title - maybe it was misleading. I need to know _how many_ bytes to read for an _arbitrary file descriptor_.

Comment: What file descriptor? You know how many bytes should you read!

Comment: No I don't (yet). I have a function which takes an arbitrary number of file descriptors I want to monitor using `select()` and flush afterwards. At this place I don't now how they were created. It might be pipes, timers or BSD sockets. Maybe I have to provide in integer for each indicating how many bytes I have to read at minimum to flush them. But I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: That's not an option: this way `read()` would either block or return `0` again in case there's not enough data. I want to implement a function `flush(FD)` which takes a file descriptor and delete _all_ data in a _non blocking_ way.

Comment: No, `read` can be a partial read, it won't block if *some* bytes have been read

Comment: Actually not always. I tried to read byte wise from a FD created with `timerfd_create()` which had 8 bytes of data in it. `read()` then returns 0 for me and the data remains.

Comment: But I did suggest using a reasonably sized buffer (of several kilobytes).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your point. Currently I cannot check it but providing a larger array sounds pretty plausible (maybe I've been working too long and did't see the point :)). I'll accept your anwer then.